# Sleep interval in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've made a basic shell script, which looks for a file existence. It can get a parameter (optional) for sleep interval. If I don't give any, the default one is 60 seconds.

**Here is my code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

minutes=60
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ "$1" =~ re ]]; then
    echo $1 is not a number!
    exit 1
fi
else minutes=$1*60
fi

while [ ! -f uj_aru ]
do
last | grep Apr
sleep "$minutes"
done
```

**After** running this I get this error:
`sleep: invalid time interval '*60'`

I guess here is a small mistake with the variable, but I didn't manage to figure it out.

Comment: Change `minutes=$1*60` to `minutes=$(($1*60))`

Comment: Is it need for the autocheck file every 60 seconds?

Comment: Just note that `sleep 1m` is also a valid syntax https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-sleep-bash-scripting/

Comment: @Alex yes, if I don't give a parameter, the default time is 60 seconds. Otherwise: parameter*60 seconds

Comment: You also can use `${1-default}` to use `"default"` instead of `$1` if no parameter was given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not doing a arithmetic that way. You need to do [arithmetic evaluation](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr)  using `$((..))` as

```
minutes=$(($1*60))
```

The error is because you are passing a *literal* string input to `sleep` which it does not like.